# Window.InnerHeight is remains same in iOS 15.4 safari browser

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mobile-safari

I'm trying to make fullscreen in safari browser and for that I'm checking Window.InnerHeight for safari browser iOS 15.4
Window.InnerHeight comes same all the time even you scroll screen.

Can someone please let me know if you had same situation before?

Comment: How do you use safari browser? If you full screen means to hide the status bar, you could set the `UIStatusBarHidden` to true.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I'm using C# and its website. How can I use UIStatusBarHidden there? If I would have use xamarin then was possible but not sure how can I access this is c#.

Comment: Did you not use the Xamarin for the Mobile? We need  more informations.